# How to load demonstration data after database creation ODOO

Tags: python, odoo

i have created the database without checking `Load demonstration data`. [image]
Now my code is failing to obtain demo_user on my tests :: As expected

```
user_demo = self.env.ref('base.user_demo')
```

> ValueError: External ID not found in the system: base.user_demo

Now how can i load demonstration data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer is in your question, demonstration data is loaded only when a database is created with that "Load demonstration data" option.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the Odoo version, at least since Odoo 12 it is possible to load demo data later:

- Go to "Settings" -> "General Settings", scroll to the very bottom.
- Click "Activate the developer mode".
- Click on the little bug icon (top right) to open the developer's menu.
- Click "Become Superuser".
- Now in "Settings" -> "General Settings", scroll to the very bottom
  again
- **Click "Load demo data".**

[Screenshot: Odoo settings, load demo data link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AIs6.png)